# Is it possible to create Eclipse plugin project using Maven Tycho with 3rd party dependencies included?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho

I want to create Eclipse plugin that contains embedded database(eg. Derby) and it has JPA like EclipseLink too. Which possibly contains many 3rd party dependencies within one plugin

In addition, I'm wonder is it possible to create the plugin project using Tycho that has only one Pom file, no separate Parent-child Poms ?

For example, like below Pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.company.persistance</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
    <properties>
        <tycho-version>1.0.0</tycho-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.12.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type> 
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>luna</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>../src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>    
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I'm quite new to Maven + Tycho and the above script did not work as what I expected.

I also try to follow this tutorial but without parent-child pom
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/How_Tos/Dependency_on_pom-first_artifacts

Because I also want Maven to download 3rd party dependency and put them into Manifest.mf file later.

Is these are possible to create ?
Or are there other approaches to achieving these ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In contrast to plain Maven, Tycho uses Eclipse p2 repositories to resolve and download dependencies. If the 3rd party dependencies should be inside the plugin and not as separate plugins/bundles from a p2 repository ([Apache Derby plugins/bundles are available from Eclipse Orbit](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/)), a separate `pom.xml` is required to download the 3rd party dependencies into the plugin folder.

Comment: Thank for the answer but I would like to ask more.
As your suggested, if I created two Pom files within the same project. 
One is for the main Eclipse plugin using Tycho build
and the other is for downloading 3rd party dependencies into, let's say, Lib folder. 
This Lib folder will then loaded by the Pom from the main Eclipse plugin.

Will this structure possible to do as you suggested ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so (I haven't tried that myself). If possible, separate plugins/bundles should be preferred over in a plugin embedded JARs.